# Issue with loadbalancing on apache

Tags: linux, apache, jira, load-balancing

Please help with my task. 
I'm must to install apache which will be balance connections by nodes (P.S. there is JIRA app nodes, if this is important).

I find how to do this, and once i have do this, and all works correctly. But in this time i put the same part of code in the httpd.conf

```
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>


        ProxyRequests off
        ServerName jira-host
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/certs/jira-host.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/certs/jira-host.key"

        ProxyTimeout 900
        Timeout 900
        SSLSessionCacheTimeout 1800
        <Proxy balancer://jiracluster>
                BalancerMember http://jira-host1:8080 route=node1
                BalancerMember http://jira-host2:8080 route=node2
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from none
                Allow from all

                ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
        </Proxy>
        <Location /balancer-manager>
                SetHandler balancer-manager

                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
        ProxyPass / balancer://jiracluster/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName jira-host

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://jira-host [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

And after restart apache get the standart apache hello page, instead balancing.
What i do wrong? please help.
Thx.

Comment: Do you have other conf files? I would usually do this in nginx alot less overhead and easier to do.

Comment: no, only standart file's in conf.d folder. But i cant remove it because got error in starting apache

Comment: check the other config files as something is routing port 80 or 443 to that.

Comment: Man!! Thank you!! You're awesome! I found in ssl.conf virtual host. Thank you again!

Comment: Ill make answer so you can mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you check all your configuration files.
It would seem that another file is still routing traffic to the default apache file.
Please check all your port 80/443 config files.